# Using IF/ELSE in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Can someone help to achieve IF/ELSE in mongoDB? I use below code in SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @p =1
IF @p =1
PRINT @p
ELSE PRINT "NO"
```

I tried the below codes in MongoDB but could not succeed.

```
var p=1
{ $cond: { if: p=1, then: print(p), else: print("NO") } }
var p=1
{ $cond: { if: p=1, print(p), print("NO") } }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean the MongoDB shell? If yes then just use JavaScript like so

```
var p = 1;
if (p == 1) { print(p); } else { print('NO'); }
```